# seeking for alternative to pandas.Panel

Tags: python, pandas, panel

Suppose I have pandas dataframe with multiindexing, ['name' 'date'],

```
                               value
name             date               
069500 KS Equity 2013-01-02  27130.0
069660 KS Equity 2013-01-02  27110.0
091160 KS Equity 2013-01-02  16140.0
091170 KS Equity 2013-01-02   7540.0
...
292160 KS Equity 2018-03-30  14690.0
292190 KS Equity 2018-03-30  14720.0
292340 KS Equity 2018-03-30   9970.0
292500 KS Equity 2018-03-30  14720.0
292730 KS Equity 2018-03-30  14680.0
```

Here, how could I make 'date column in a chronological order to resemble panel data? I was about to use `pandas.Panel` formula but they are missing..My sub-goal is making dataframe as follows.

```
                               value
name             date               
069500 KS Equity 2013-01-02  27130.0
069500 KS Equity 2013-01-03  28476.0
069500 KS Equity 2013-01-04  20683.0
069500 KS Equity 2013-01-05  25586.0
...
292730 KS Equity 2018-03-26  16357.0
292730 KS Equity 2018-03-27  16486.0
292730 KS Equity 2018-03-28  16659.0
292730 KS Equity 2018-03-29  16495.0
292730 KS Equity 2018-03-30  14680.0
```

What I've tried was as follows. However they all failed as of yet..

```
df.reset_index(level=1, inplace = True)
df.sort_index(level='date')
df.groupby(level = 'date')
```

If you have any ideas, please enlighten me..I welcome any duplicates though you might be bothered..Thank you all..Have a good day~

Comment: I think need `df = df.sort_index(level=['date', 'name'])`

Comment: or swapped arguments :)

Comment: df.index = df.index.swaplevel(1,0)    like this?

Comment: `df = df.sort_index(level=[ 'name', 'date'])` :)

Comment: That works!!!! Thanks again, @jezrael and also sorry for making repetitive questions....

Comment: No problem, just realised simpliest solution is `df = df.sort_index()`